# mvn test not running Spring Boot test

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit

I have a simple test class in a SpringBoot application.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(RestaurantController.class)

public class RestaurantControllerTest {

  @Test
  public void displayRestaurant() throws Exception{
  ...
  }
}
```

My relevant pom.xml is this.

```
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

...

However when I run mvn test, Maven doesn't discover the test class with the [Info] No tests to run.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm also not sure if adding the surefire plugin is necessary as I have the test class ending with 'Test' and I don't need any test reports.

Comment: First remove the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin completely from your pom file.. cause I assume you are using spring-boot-parent? Furthermore where have you located your test `src/test/java` ?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? If you are using 2.3.0, then it defaults to JUnit 5, which does not need the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation. You also don't need the maven-surefire-plugin config at all normally. If you really want it, use the latest stable version ([2.22.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin))